# How to pass parameter as a file in AWS CloudFormation deploy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I was trying to update the existing CloudFormation stack with the below command.

```sh
aws cloudformation deploy
```

there is no option to pass parameter **file** with **deploy** option. we tried to pass parameter file with --parameter-overrides but it's giving the below error.

> value passed to --parameter-overrides must be of format Key=Value

the command we try to execute is

```sh
aws cloudformation deploy --template-file sg.yml --stack-name Common-SG --parameter-overrides ip.json --no-execute-changeset
```

is there any way to pass the parameters in file with **aws cloudformation deploy**

Comment: looks like similar issues and workarounds here: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/3274#issuecomment-498812550

Comment: @PatMyron thank you

Answer (score 16):

Passing a parameters stored as JSON in a local file looks like:

```
aws cloudformation deploy \
    --stack-name demo \
    --template-file test.yml --parameter-overrides file://test.json  \
```

and the test.json like this.

```
{
    "Parameters": {
      "BucketName": "myawesometestdemo"
    }
}
```

test.yml

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Simple S3 Bucket test
Parameters:
  BucketName:
    Type: String
    Description: The name of the S3 Bucket to create

Metadata:

  AWS::CloudFormation::Interface:
    ParameterLabels:
      BucketName:
        default: S3 Bucket Name

Resources:

  S3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Ref BucketName
```

aws cli version :

```
aws --version
aws-cli/2.2.35 Python/3. XXX
```

Comment: This didn't work for me at first. Turns out that I still hade AWS CLI v1 installed. After updating to v2, it worked.

Comment: This didn't work even using aws-cli/2.0.30

```['{'] value passed to --parameter-overrides must be of format Key=Value```

Answer (score 3):

workaround for this issue is pass parameters with **jq** command.

```
yum install jq
```

Below is the syntax for the same.

```
aws cloudformation deploy --template-file sg.yml --stack-name Common-SG --parameter-overrides $(jq -r '.[] | [.ParameterKey, .ParameterValue] | "\(.[0])=\(.[1])"' ip.json) --no-execute-changeset
```

Answer (score 3):

You can actually pass a file path to Cloudformation deploy --parameter-overrides. The below syntax worked for me:

```
aws cloudformation deploy \
  --template-file template.yml \
  --stack-name my-stack \
  --parameter-overrides file://path/to_parameter_file.json
```

where file://path/to_parameter_file.json represents the path to the parameter you want to pass.

Comment: Does this also work with yaml? :)

Answer (score 2):

this might be too late already, but for the sake of future similar issue I found this answer on (https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/issues/111)

The command should look like:

```
aws cloudformation deploy --template-file sg.yml --stack-name Common-SG --parameter-overrides $(cat params.properties) --no-execute-changeset
```

Now this is not going to be a json file, since "parameter-overrieds" expects a Key=Value pairs!

Comment: What happens with line endings here? Don't you need something like `$(cat params.properties | tr "\n" " ")` to replace line endings with space?

Comment: @Xabs, ya that's needed, thanks!! However, I did manually add a new line to the props file already to avoid that :)

Comment: huge thabks bro ;)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with the files

Initially I had used

```
[
  {
    "ParameterKey": "EnvironmentStage",
    "ParameterValue": "sandbox"
  }
]
```

This did not work I got the error that the elements should be of Class 'Str' and not an ordered.Dict

2nd iteration I changed it to as mentioned in the earlier responses that did not work either

finally I have it as

```
[
  "EnvironmentStage=sandbox"
]
```

and it works well

Comment: Thank you @DataGuru, for showing the right format. I have also tested several formats of the parameters json file. Out of all 3 different supported format those worked for me, this is the simplest one: `["key1=vlaue1", "key2=value2", ...]` .

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this based on aws doc:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/deploy/index.html

```
aws cloudformation deploy --template-file /path_to_template/template.json --stack-name my-new-stack --parameter-overrides Key1=Value1 Key2=Value2
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in buildspec file:
Structure of parameters.json:

```
[
  {
    "ParameterKey": "Key1",
    "ParameterValue": "Value1"
  }
]
```

and then:

```
post_build:
        commands:
            - echo "Start build..."
            - aws cloudformation deploy --template-file ./template.yaml --parameter-overrides $(jq -r '.[] | [.ParameterKey, .ParameterValue] | "\(.[0])=\(.[1])"' ./parameters/parameters.json) --stack-name ${stackName} --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND
```